# how to access the value of <select> in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not able to pass the value from my  tab to me $scope object.
This is my html snippet.

```
<div ng-controller="RouteController">
            <select ng-model="selector" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">

            </select>
            <button ng-click="selectFn()">Go</button>
</div>
```

My JS code is as below.

```
sampleApp.controller('RouteController', function($scope){

        $scope.options=[
            {label: '1', url:'1.html'},
            {label: '2', url:'2.html'}  

        ];
        $scope.selectFn = function($scope){
                alert("selector");

        }

    });
```

I am not sure how to pass the value of the selected item to the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get into trouble by using ng-model like this since ng-model might not be updated whenever the value changes :

```
ng-model="selector"
```

A proper way of using ng-model would be;

```
ng-model="opt.selector"
```

By doing that, it can be reached by $scope like this;

```
$scope.opt.selector
```

Then you should modify the code as follows :

```
$scope.selectFn = function(){
     console.log($scope.opt.selector);
}
```

To be simple, if you are using ng-model, you have to include a dot.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Vineet's answer, you don't need to do anything to "pass" the value. Angular's model binding takes care of that for you.

Because you have this: 
    ng-model="selector"...

When ever the selected value changes, the selector object is automatically updated in $scope with the new value. So, just execute selectFn()  and make sure you are referencing your object correctly via $scope:

```
$scope.selectFn = function(){
    alert($scope.selector);
}
```